# tsconfig "module" property with Node server + Create React app

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I have a node server and a create react app in one repo, I am trying to use one tsconfig.json. For some reason, CRA wants `module: "esnext"` and the backened server won't boot without `module: "commonjs"`.

Can someone explain to me what's going on here? How can I get them both to use the same module setting? Is it possible to have it set to something and work for both? Do I need to tsconfig files?

Comment: SO it turns it this is because CRE uses webpack, and the node code uses just node, so for the backend ts wants to use commonjs since that’s what node speaks natively, and tsc transpiles your imports to requires. CRE uses webpack and doesn't need to turn the modules into commonjs it just bundles them up.

Answer (score 2):

Create React App uses webpack which uses [Babel with typescript transform](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/typescript-and-babel-7/), which is not the "normal" way to use typescript. CRA will modify your `tsconfig.json` each time you run `react-scripts` to make it work the way CRA expects things to work.

You can either [eject](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/alternatives-to-ejecting#docsNav) and reconfigure webpack to bundle js code compiled by typescript, without involving Babel, then you don't have any restrictions on `tsconfig.json`.

Or you can have two files, `tsconfig.json` for CRA and `tsconfig.node.json` for server code, both [extending](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#configuration-inheritance-with-extends) the third `tsconfig.base.json` which has common settings.

Comment: How would you have the CRA application point to `tsconfig.json` and the node app point to `tsconfig.node.json`?

Comment: For node I use something like this in my package.json ```tsc: tsc --config tsconfig.node.json``` and then run ```npm run tsc``` to build node code. You can also pass the ```--watch flag```